# The "density" of gaps in countable arithmetically saturated models or Peano Arithmetic

Tags: model-theory, peano-axioms

Suppose that $\mathcal{M}$ is a countable, arithmetically saturated model of $\mathsf{PA}$ with universe $M$, the *gap* about some $a\in\mathcal{M}$ is defined as the set of all $b \in M$ such that $\mathcal{M}\models b\le a \le t(b) \vee a\le b\le t(a)$ for some term $t(v)$.

Note that the relation "$x$ is in $\mathrm{gap}(y)$" is an equivalence relation, resulting in the fact that each two gaps of $\mathcal{M}$ are either identical or disjoint.

I have been wondering if for any two gaps $\mathrm{gap}(a)<\mathrm{gap}(b)$ there is some $c\in M$ such that $\mathrm{gap}(a)<\mathrm{gap}(c)<\mathrm{gap}(b)$?

Any help (or reference) would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: If your definitions agree with those in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.4687&rep=rep1&type=pdf), it's highly relevant that you're working in a formulation of PA that has a term for every function definable without parameters. So in the definition of gap, _term_ means something much more than "polynomial with coefficients from $\mathbb{N}$", i.e. term in the language $\{0,1,+,*,<\}$.

Comment: This question actually rose trying to understand the proof of lemma 2.5 in this very same paper, so my definitions do coincide with the ones appearing in the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact true (even for recursively saturated models of $\mathsf{PA}$): there is a gap between any two gaps $\mathrm{gap}(a) < \mathrm{gap}(b)$ in $\mathcal{M}$.

As mentioned in "The Structure of Models of Peano Arithmetic" (by Kossak and Schmerl), page 17, in the case where $\mathcal{M}$ is recursively saturated the elementary cut $\inf (\mathrm{gap}(b))$ is *tall*, i.e it has no last gap. Therefore $\sup(\mathrm{gap}(a)) < \inf (\mathrm{gap}(b))$ and there is some $\mathrm{gap}(a) < c < \mathrm{gap}(b)$ which must satisfy $\mathrm{gap}(a) < \mathrm{gap}(c) < \mathrm{gap}(b)$.

Comment: One can write down a type $p(x)$ which says, informally, that $gap(a) < x$ and $x < gap(b)$. You can check that such a type is recursive (you can recursively enumerate the Skolem terms in the language).